# Is it possible to copy a file to a docker image without running it as a container?

Tags: docker

I want to copy some files to a docker image of mine that I inherited, however I don't want to launch it as a container and export, as I will lose my environmental variables.

Unfortunately I do not have the original Dockerfile.

I have tried saving (versus exporting) the image to a tar and then changing a layer with some new files and then loading the tars but this seems to break the "imageness" of the image (I get an error about trying to load the re-tarred file).

Comment: Do you want to copy this file at build moment? I mean, are you using "FROM my_image" but my_image need some file before FROM sentence?

Comment: No, I suppose I could just create a new build from my old image. That would work, now wouldn't it? Sorry, I am new to Docker

Comment: Didn't understood what you want. I assume you have a docker image in which you want to copy some files. Is it this case?

Comment: could you share us the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Dockerfile:

```
FROM yourcurrentimage
COPY thefileyouwant /theplace/it/shouldgo
```

Then:

```
$ docker built -t newimage .
```

However, this is... not a good plan in the long term. You'll lose your hard drive, or need a fix, etc.. Better to figure out how to build the original image from scratch.

Comment: I don’t even know if I have access to all the files that made up the original image. And the image will be stored on ECR